# Access won't recognise a file in System 32

Tags: vb.net, vba, system

I have a database that looks for a file hidden in System 32 to prevent users from copying the database to another computer. However when I run the sub in VB, Access doesn't recognise the file and goes straight to closing the database

```
If Dir("C:\Windows\System32\theFile") = "" Then
    If MsgBox("This is not a registered version of this program.", vbCritical, "ERROR") Then
        DoCmd.Quit
    End If
End If
```

How do I get Access to find the file?

Comment: Are you running 32 bit Access on 64 bit Windows?

Comment: This is a train-wreck waiting to happen, drastically inconveniencing your paying customer and providing no real piracy protection.  Windows doesn't need to be installed in c:\windows and the file is not accessible unless you use SysNative instead of System32 on a 64-bit operating system.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to windows XP or older, or dont put it in System32.  Vista/7/8 doesn't like you messing with that folder.

You might want to change the location to somewhere that is not affected by UAC and change the attributes to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the hidden attribute with the DIR function to find hidden files:

```
If Dir("C:\Windows\System32\theFile", FileAttribute.Hidden) = "" Then
```